# How to make my script to draw beyond 25 candles?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My script calculates the price distance between OHLC. I found this script online and modified it to suit my needs. The issue is that it only labels up to 25 candles.

I believe there's something wrong that I'm not quite grasping about the 'label.new' code. I've tried to search and understand it better, but I couldn't find much.

```
indicator(title='Distance OHLC', overlay=true)

//Declare Bullish and Bearish
Bullish = close>open
Bearish = close<open

// Calculate the distance from the Low to the close and from the High to the close
//Bearish
BearishFromLowToClose = (close - low)
BearishFromTopToOpen = (high - open)
//Bullish
BullishFromTopToClose = (high - close)
BullishFromLowToOpen = (open - low)

// Create the labels and variables
CandleBearishClosed = if (Bearish)
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=low, text=str.tostring(BearishFromLowToClose, '#.######'), textcolor = color.white, color=color.rgb(76, 175, 79, 100), style=label.style_label_up, size=size.small)
CandleBearishOpened = if (Bearish)
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=high, text=str.tostring(BearishFromTopToOpen, '#.######'), textcolor = color.white, color=color.rgb(255, 82, 82, 100), style=label.style_label_down, size=size.small)

CandleBullishOpened = if (Bullish)
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=high, text=str.tostring(BullishFromTopToClose, '#.######'), textcolor = color.white, color=color.rgb(255, 82, 82, 100), style=label.style_label_down, size=size.small)
CandleBullishClosed = if (Bullish)
    label.new(x=bar_index, y=low, text=str.tostring(BullishFromLowToOpen, '#.######'), textcolor = color.white, color=color.rgb(76, 175, 79, 100), style=label.style_label_up, size=size.small)
```

I'm looking for functionality similar to 'plot' all thru the chart, but I need the values.